# Neo4j Cypher and query construction based on condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a following Cypher query:

```
MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch:Characteristic) 
WHERE d.id = {ownerDecisionId} and ch.lowerName = LOWER({name}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)-[rcho:CONTAINS]->(cho:CharacteristicOption) 
RETURN ch, rcho, cho
```

Sometimes I don't need the following part of the query:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)-[rcho:CONTAINS]->(cho:CharacteristicOption)
```

Right now I'm going to introduce a new method with a different query for this purpose but would like to ask - is it a preferred approach in order to achieve this or there is another way in Cypher..for example I can introduce some new boolean variable and based on its value I can add a condition in order to return (or no) the following information: `OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)-[rcho:CONTAINS]->(cho:CharacteristicOption)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following query may do what you want without needing to use APOC. It assumes that `executeOptionalMatch` is a boolean parameter that indicates whether the `OPTIONAL MATCH` should be executed.

```
MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch:Characteristic) 
WHERE d.id = {ownerDecisionId} and ch.lowerName = LOWER({name}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)-[rcho:CONTAINS]->(cho:CharacteristicOption)
WHERE {executeOptionalMatch}
RETURN ch, rcho, cho
```

You can get the [PROFILE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/query-tuning/how-do-i-profile-a-query/) of the query to see if the `OPTIONAL MATCH` does any significant work before its `WHERE` is executed. The profile I get in my version of neo4j shows that the `WHERE` filtering is done before the `OPTIONAL MATCH` does any real work.

Comment: Thanks, I like this approach because I don't need to play with APOC infrastructure right now.

Comment: The more obvious and efficient solution :) really useful, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try [installing APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) procedures and using `apoc.when`.

Considering these parameters:

```
:params {ownerDecisionId:10, name:'Jon',executeOptionalMatch:true}
```

You can run a query like this:

```
MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:DEFINED_BY]-(ch:Characteristic) 
WHERE d.id = {ownerDecisionId} and ch.lowerName = LOWER({name}) 
CALL apoc.when({executeOptionalMatch}, 'OPTIONAL MATCH (ch)-[rcho:CONTAINS]->(cho:CharacteristicOption) RETURN rcho, cho', '', {ch:ch}) YIELD value
RETURN ch, value.rcho, value.cho
```

The `OPTIONAL MATCH` will be executed only when `ownerDecisionId = true`.

*Note: remember to install APOC procedures according the version of Neo4j you are using. Take a look in the [Version Compatibility Matrix](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_version_compatibility_matrix).*

Comment: Thanks! I'll try APOC.